# Bothering vs having bothered

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between following two sentences:

1. I'm worried about not passing the test.
2. I'm worried about not having passed the test.

Or,

1. Excuse me for bothering you.
2. Excuse me for having bothered you.

If they mean aren't the same, are they used differently in different conditions with different meanings?

Comment: The tenses are not the same, but there is a degree of overlap.

Comment: You might be more likely to use #2 when *leaving* (i.e. - ***after*** you bothered someone). But most people would just use the simple tense of #1 in all contexts (immediately *before you start* bothering someone, *while* you're doing that, and *after* you've done it).

Comment: The meaning is identical, but in the first sentence, the bothering is taking place in the present, while in the second, the preterite puts the action in the past. The first would be used as an interjection, for instance when asking for help from a busy clerk. The second might be used to apologize for a past mistake.

Comment: @yubrajsharma Inserting a space after the full stop following a number in a list (**2. **) causes the numbered list magically to order itself. Look at the "before" and "after" by clicking on the tiny [edited 1 min ago](http://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/105485/revisions) link under your question to see how this works.

Comment: @pE Dent,I Saw them, thank you for having teached me.
 Is this 'thank you for having teached me' correct to say?
Or, Thank you to have teached me.
Or.Thank you for teaching me.
Are they all used differently?

Comment: The past participle of _teach_ is _taught._ It is an _irregular_ verb. You would say "Thank you for having _taught_ me." There are many irregular verbs in English. A good list is [**here.**](https://www.usingenglish.com/reference/irregular-verbs/)

Answer (score 4):

> I'm worried about not passing the test.

might be referring to a test you've already taken, or one that you've yet to take.

> I'm worried about not having passed the test.

unambiguously refers to a test you've already taken.

Not directly related to your question, but in either case, the likely meaning is "worried about whether I have passed/am going to pass the test", but could also mean "I didn't pass the test, and I'm worried about what the consequences of that will be".

The "bothered" examples are just the same: "having bothered" places the bothering firmly in the past, while "bothering" does not specify whether it is present (or future, though that is rather unlikely in this case) or past.